# Connecting to a mysql database without keeping details in the script

Tags: php, mysql, include, require

I am attempting to create a separate login file for database connections as I am not too fond of having all the access details on each page that requires database access.

I have created a separate file on my server that contains the variables required for a successful login and then use the;

```
include_once('path_to_file/filename.php');
```

to get the variables and then use;

```
$dbconnection = mysqli_connect("$hostname","$username","$password","$database") or die ("Could not connect to the server");
```

but the connection fails every time. I tried including the connection script in the file I am attempting to include but then I get this message:

```
Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

I'm not really sure how to fix this, but every page in my server more or less access the database and I think it has to be a security risk having login details replicated everywhere!

Anyone have any suggestions or alternatives?

databaseloging format is:

```
<?php
# parameters for connection to MySQL database
    $hostname="hostname";
    $database="databasename";
    $username="username";
    $password="password";
?>
```

P.S. I have also tried require and got the same result.

Comment: echo $hostname;echo $username;?what you get

Comment: How exactly does the included file look like?

Comment: I can echo the variables from within the main script, but the mysqli_connect wont accept them.
 Ive updated  the above to format the code properly.

Comment: Strip the quotation marks from the mysqli_connect command: `mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $database)`

Comment: @Reeno Technically, that will still work as double quoted strings can still identify variables

Comment: How are you passing the db details to the seperate file you have created

Comment: this looks more like error in mysqld

Comment: did your connection work prior to your attempt to keep all your configuration variables in one file ?

Comment: My connection worked fine untl i tried to move the variables, the server is running as I can access it on unaltered pages. To create the file i just wrote it in notepad, changed it to a .php and then entered the variables I wanted to store as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

Also when using multiple MySQL connections in PHP, you have to supply a fourth argument telling PHP to actually create new connections like this (this is very important, if you are using two connections to the same host):

```
$db1 = mysql_connect($host1, $user1, $passwd1, true);
$db2 = mysql_connect($host2, $user2, $passwd2, true);
```

If the fourth argument is not used, and the parameters are the same, then PHP will return the same link and no new connection will be made.

After this you should use "mysql_query" with an extra parameter than defines which connection to use:

```
$res1 = mysql_query($sql1, $db1) or die(mysql_error($res1));
$res2 = mysql_query($sql2, $db2) or die(mysql_error($res2));
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

Comment: technically permission 755 is enough.

Comment: the mysql database and server are working correctly and not local. I can connect to it fine if i declase the variables within the file, I just cant seem to import them - I also stripped the quotes from the mysqli_connect line and no difference. It looks like its not getting the variables before attempting the connection for some reason, but im not sure.

Comment: How are you passing the db details to the seperate file you have created

Comment: Im not passing them, I wrote the file in notepad++, made it a .php file and uploaded it on to my server. The file is simply a selection of variables. I thnen call the file to the page using    include_once('path_to_file/filename.php');

Comment: Can you echo the db connection variables when mysql returns error.

Put a condition like if($filename){mysql1_connect().....}

Comment: I can echo them yes, I can have all 4 appear in the browser, but then still a connection error under it.

Comment: is the hostname same for all connections

Comment: Yes, all data connections are identical, all that changes is the table names within the database, which isnt contained within the files.

Comment: oh then you can use same connection right. Why there is a need for always connecting and selecting db. You can reuse the same connection as well as the db

Comment: even across multiple pages? I htought I would need to reconnect when ever I navigated to a new page? For security I also tend to close the connection after query is completed.

Comment: You can use the same db connection through out your pages.